# Como usar uma thread específica de uma classe com múltiplas threads?

Tags: java, thread

Estou com uma classe chamada Bola onde nela tenho uma *thread* que faz umas bolinhas se movimentarem na fase 1 de um do jogo. É possível eu implementar nessa mesma classe outra *thread* que faça as bolinhas se movimentarem de forma diferente no caso para fase 2 do jogo, se possível deixem um exemplo de como posso ter as 2 *thread* na mesma classe e como posso acessar cada uma.

Aqui está o código:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Bola extends Thread {
private int x,y,tamanho;
private int direcao;
int opcao;

public Bola(int x,int y,int tamanho){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.tamanho=tamanho;
}

@Override

public void run() {
    super.run();
    while(1==1){

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(x<150){
            direcao=1;

        }
        if(x>700){
            direcao=0;

        }
        if(direcao==1){
            x++;

        }
        if(direcao==0){
            x--;
        }
    }
//aqui gostaria de por outra thread, do mesmo jeito da primeira,porém vai //alterar o y...dai na classe da fase eu gostaria de chamar apenas essa thread //que altera o y

}




public Rectangle colisao(){
    return new Rectangle(x, y, tamanho, tamanho);
}


public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int getTamanho() {
    return tamanho;
}

public void setTamanho(int tamanho) {
    this.tamanho = tamanho;
}

}
```

Comment: A pergunta está meio troncha mas falando muito genericamente parece melhor implementar o comportamento de cada fase numa classe diferente

Comment: A fase 1 do jogo ocorre **simultaneamente** à fase 2? Se não, não há razão para se criar duas threads... Use a mesma! O que você precisa é: a) uma classe para cada fase, como sugerido por @epx; ou b) uma classe **parametrizável** - se o comportamento da bolinhas é parecido em ambas as fases, o que muda é só alguns parêmetros (como velocidade, acelaração, ângulo etc). Se tiver alguma dúvida específica, poste trecho(s) do código que você já tem, e o que está causando dificuldade.

Comment: Não dá para você colocar um pouco de código aqui para tentarmos entender exatamente como você estruturou isso?

Comment: Seria essa questão um trabalho de escola?

Comment: O título da sua pergunta está um pouco esquisito mesmo, talvez porque você esteja misturando na pergunta uma ideia de solução que você já tem. Talvez se vc mudar o título (e talvez até mesmo o texto, não sei) mais para o que você quer fazer, a questão atraia mais pessoas interessadas em responder.

Answer (score 5):

Você não "acessa" uma thread. Você inicia ela, e ela continua executando. Diga-se de passagem, o seu programa já está rodando em uma thread -- o que você faz é iniciar *novas* threads.

É possível coordenar threads usando diversos recursos: sincronização, semáforos, objetos compartilhados, etc. Mas para saber o que é mais apropriado no seu caso, é necessário definir  *porque* você deseja uma thread para cada fase e o que isso vai trazer de benefício?

Também seria útil que você mostrasse detalhes da classe já existente, para sabermos como essa thread é criada e utilizada.

Answer (score 3):

Como o @rdllopes já mencionou na resposta dele, não é uma boa prática fazer os seus objetos serem executados em threads diferentes, pois é muito comum que jogos tenham muitos objetos e fica bastante custoso para o sistema operacional fazer o escalonamento de muitas threads.

Em jogos é mais comum ter apenas uma ou duas threads, como por exemplo uma para gerenciar a interface do usuário (a thread principal, digamos) e outra para gerenciar o [game loop](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/tips-for-writing-the-main-game-loop) do jogo.

Você não mencionou se está fazendo um jogo só pra aprender programação em Java ou para produzir um jogo realmente. Se não for para aprendizado, muito provavelmente será mais fácil (e produtivo) se você utilizar um [Motor de Jogo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_de_jogo) pronto. Tais ferramentas facilitam muitíssimo o desenvolvimento de jogos por que já incluem o game loop, funções de áudio e de tratamento de entrada, e (em muitos casos) até mesmo bibliotecas para a simulação da física e da inteligência artificial. No caso do Java, um motor bastante famoso é o [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/).

Além do assunto da thread a sua questão também é sobre como ter comportamentos distintos em um objeto de jogo (uma bola). Por isso, eu preparei um exemplo para sugerir uma forma de implementação.

Antes de começar, é importante que você se familiarize com [vetores](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vetor_%28matem%C3%A1tica%29) e com a classe `Vector2D` (de autoria de [Jadrian Miles](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps108/fall04/code/xooga/xooga/Vector2D.java)). Vetores são importantes no código porque são utilizados para representar a posição das bolas e sua velocidade.

```java
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.lang.Math;

/**
 * An extension to the relatively impotent java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double,
 * Vector2D allows mathematical manipulation of 2-component vectors.
 * 
 * @author Jadrian Miles
 * @version 20031122
 */
public class Vector2D extends Point2D.Double {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double#Point2D.Double()
     */
    public Vector2D() {
        super();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double#Point2D.Double()
     */
    public Vector2D(double x, double y) {
        super(x, y);
    }

    /**
     * Copy constructor
     */
    public Vector2D(Vector2D v) {
        x = v.x;
        y = v.y;
    }

    /**
     * @return the radius (length, modulus) of the vector in polar coordinates
     */
    public double getR() {
        return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /**
     * @return the angle (argument) of the vector in polar coordinates in the
     *         range [-pi/2, pi/2]
     */
    public double getTheta() {
        return Math.atan2(y, x);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double#setLocation(double, double)
     */
    public void set(double x, double y) {
        super.setLocation(x, y);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the vector given polar arguments.
     * 
     * @param r
     *            The new radius
     * @param t
     *            The new angle, in radians
     */
    public void setPolar(double r, double t) {
        super.setLocation(r * Math.cos(t), r * Math.sin(t));
    }

    /** Sets the vector's radius, preserving its angle. */
    public void setR(double r) {
        double t = getTheta();
        setPolar(r, t);
    }

    /** Sets the vector's angle, preserving its radius. */
    public void setTheta(double t) {
        double r = getR();
        setPolar(r, t);
    }

    /** The sum of the vector and rhs */
    public Vector2D plus(Vector2D rhs) {
        return new Vector2D(x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y);
    }

    /** The difference of the vector and rhs: this - rhs */
    public Vector2D minus(Vector2D rhs) {
        return new Vector2D(x - rhs.x, y - rhs.y);
    }

    public boolean equals(Vector2D rhs) {
        return x == rhs.x && y == rhs.y;
    }

    /** Product of the vector and scalar */
    public Vector2D scalarMult(double scalar) {
        return new Vector2D(scalar * x, scalar * y);
    }

    /** Dot product of the vector and rhs */
    public double dotProduct(Vector2D rhs) {
        return x * rhs.x + y * rhs.y;
    }

    /**
     * Since Vector2D works only in the x-y plane, (u x v) points directly along
     * the z axis. This function returns the value on the z axis that (u x v)
     * reaches.
     * 
     * @return signed magnitude of (this x rhs)
     */
    public double crossProduct(Vector2D rhs) {
        return x * rhs.y - y * rhs.x;
    }

    /** Product of components of the vector: compenentProduct( <x y>) = x*y. */
    public double componentProduct() {
        return x * y;
    }

    /** Componentwise product: <this.x*rhs.x, this.y*rhs.y> */
    public Vector2D componentwiseProduct(Vector2D rhs) {
        return new Vector2D(x * rhs.x, y * rhs.y);
    }

    /**
     * An alias for getR()
     * @return the length of this
     */
    public double length() {
        return getR();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new vector with the same direction as the vector but with
     * length 1, except in the case of zero vectors, which return a copy of
     * themselves.
     */
    public Vector2D unitVector() {
        if (getR() != 0) {
            return new Vector2D(x / getR(), y / getR());
        }
        return new Vector2D(0,0);
    }

    /** Polar version of the vector, with radius in x and angle in y */
    public Vector2D toPolar() {
        return new Vector2D(Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y), Math.atan2(y, x));
    }

    /** Rectangular version of the vector, assuming radius in x and angle in y*/
    public Vector2D toRect() {
        return new Vector2D(x * Math.cos(y), x * Math.sin(y));
    }

    /** @return Standard string representation of a vector: "<x, y>" */
    public String toString() {
        return "<" + x + ", " + y + ">";
    }
}
```

A classe mais importante do exemplo que eu preparei se chama simplemenge `Game`. Eu fiz ela como uma Applet, mas você pode construir uma janela em Swing, por exemplo. O princípio é o mesmo: ela implementa a interface `Runnable` porque ela é quem implementa a thread do game loop! O código está a seguir:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

/**
 * Classe principal, de implementação do jogo.
 * Exemplo para ilustração no SOPT.
 * @author Luiz C. Vieira
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JApplet implements Runnable {

    /** Thread de execução da applet. */
    private Thread m_oMainThread;

    /** Indicador de que o jogo está em execução. */
    private boolean m_bRunning;

    /** Taxa de quadros por segundo (framerate) ideal do jogo. */
    private static float FPS = 1000f / 60f; 

    /**
     * Método de inicialização da applet do jogo.
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();

        // Define tamanho da janela de jogo
        setSize(800, 600);

        // Adiciona a cena ao jogo
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(GameScene.instance);

        // Cria e inicia a thread de execução do jogo
        m_bRunning = true;
        m_oMainThread = new Thread(this);
    }

    /**
     * Método de início da applet do jogo.
     */
    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        m_oMainThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Método de interrupção da applet do jogo.
     */
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
        m_bRunning = false;
    }

    /**
     * Método de execução da thread da applet do jogo.
     * Basicamente implementa o game loop, atualizando na cena
     * todos os componentes a cada quadro (cada iteração).
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {

        long lPrevious = System.nanoTime() / 1000000;
        long lLag = 0;

        // Gameloop do jogo
        while(m_bRunning) {

            // Contabilização de tempo
            long lCurrent = System.nanoTime() / 1000000;
            long lElapsed = lCurrent - lPrevious;
            lPrevious = lCurrent;
            lLag += lElapsed;

            // Processamento de entrada (teclado, mouse, etc) vai aqui!
            // TODO

            // Atualização do mundo!
            // Faz chamadas de update enquanto o número desejado de quadros
            // por segundo não tiver sido atingido
            while(lLag >= Game.FPS)
            {
                GameScene.instance.update();
                lLag -= Game.FPS;
            }

            // Renderização do jogo!
            GameScene.instance.repaint();

        }
    }
}
```

Essa classe funciona assim:

- Na inicialização, ela adiciona o objeto singleton da classe `GameScene` (o cenário do jogo) sob um layout.
- Então, cria uma thread que executará o método `run` do próprio objeto (`this`).
- O método `run` contém propriamente o game loop. O que ele faz é continuamente executar `GameScene.instance.update();` (a simulação do mundo) e `GameScene.instance.repaint();` (a atualização da tela do jogo), buscando controlar a taxa de atualização dos quadros do jogo (procure ler mais sobre *framerate* e gameloop na Internet se já não souber do que se trata, pois vale a pena).

A outra classe chama-se `GameScene` e se trata meramente de uma classe que herda de `JComponent` para ser adicionada à Applet, mas que especialmente contém todos os objetos do jogo. Note que eu fiz essa classe um singleton, mas idealmente você pode ter diferentes instâncias dela para cada fase. Ou seja, a ideia é que essa classe representa a cena ou fase atual do jogo. Aqui está o código:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

/**
 * Classe de implementação de cenas de jogo.
 * @author Luiz C. Vieira
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameScene extends JComponent {

    /** Referência estática do vetor da gravidade. */
    public static Vector2D GRAVITY = new Vector2D(0, 1);

    /** Referência estática dos limites do mundo. */
    public static Rectangle BOUNDS = new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600);

    /** Matriz com as bolas instanciadas na cena. */
    private ArrayList<Ball> m_lsBalls;

    /** Instância singleton da cena. */
    public static GameScene instance = new GameScene();

    /**
     * Construtor protegido.
     */
    protected GameScene() {
        // Cria 10 bolas aleatoriamente
        m_lsBalls = new ArrayList<Ball>();

        Color aColors[] = { Color.white, Color.blue, Color.red, Color.green, Color.orange, Color.cyan };
        Random oRnd = new Random();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            int iRadius = oRnd.nextInt(50) + 10;
            Color oColor = aColors[oRnd.nextInt(aColors.length)];

            Ball oBall = new Ball(iRadius, oColor);

            oBall.setPosition(new Vector2D(oRnd.nextDouble() * 800, oRnd.nextDouble() * 600));
            oBall.setVelocity(new Vector2D(oRnd.nextDouble() * 10, oRnd.nextDouble() * 10));

            // A primeira bola não perde velocidade!
            if(i == 1) {
                oBall.setBounciness(1);
                oBall.setVelocity(new Vector2D(5, 0));
            }

            // A terceira bola não tem gravidade!
            else if(i == 3) {
                oBall.setOwnGravity(new Vector2D(0, 0));
                oBall.setOwnGravityEnabled(true);
            }

            // A quinta bola tem a gravidade invertida (isto é, "cai pra cima")!
            else if(i == 5) {
                oBall.setOwnGravity(new Vector2D(0, -1));
                oBall.setOwnGravityEnabled(true);
            }

            m_lsBalls.add(oBall);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Método de atualização da cena. É chamado a cada quadro do jogo.
     */
    public void update() {
        // Atualiza todos os objetos em cena
        for(Ball oBall: m_lsBalls) {
            oBall.update();
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Método de pintura da cena.
     * @param g Intância com o objeto Graphics da applet para pintura. 
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Pinta o fundo da cena (simplesmente todo branco nesse exemplo)
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GameScene.BOUNDS.width, GameScene.BOUNDS.height);

        // Faz a repintura de cada um dos objetos em cena
        for(Ball oBall: m_lsBalls) {
            oBall.paint(g);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Getter de acesso aos objetos em cena.
     * @return ArrayList com os objetos na cena.
     */
    public ArrayList<Ball> getBalls() {
        return m_lsBalls;
    }
}
```

O método principal dessa classe é o `update`, que é chamado lá no game loop a cada quadro do jogo. O que esse método faz parece bem simples, mas é fundamental: ele *chama o método update de cada objeto em cena*, de forma que eles possam se atualizar de maneira apropriada. O método `paintComponent` é também importante porque é onde se implementa a renderização (desenho) da cena. Note que ele também executa o método `paint` de cada objeto para que eles possam se desenhar na tela.

> IMPORTANTE: A cena do jogo é herdada de `JComponent` porque essa classe
>   (assim como JPanel, por exemplo) já implementa
>   um controle de pintura chamado *[double buffering](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/video/1410-o-que-e-double-buffering-.htm)*. Sem esse
>   controle, a repintura da tela a cada quadro (controlada pelo game loop)
>   faz a tela piscar (efeito conhecido como *flickering*).

Você vai notar que no construtor dessa classe eu crio 5 bolas com tamanho e cores aleatórias. Mas, mais importante (e relacionado à sua questão) eu configuro as bolas 1, 3 e 5 com "comportamentos" distintos que eu defini, como por exemplo fazer com que uma não obedeça a gravidade do mundo e que outra não perca velocidade ao colidir. Dá pra você brincar ai como quiser, e a grande sacada é controlar as especificidades de cada bola por meio de atributos e alterações na classe `Ball`.

Aliás (e finalmente!), eis aqui o código da classe `Ball`:

```java
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Classe bola para exemplificação no SOPT.
     * Ela não implementa thread! Esse controle fica por parte das classes
     * Game e GameScene que executam o método update.
     * @author Luiz C. Vieira
     */
    public class Ball {

        /** Vetor com a posição atual da bola. */
        private Vector2D m_vPosition;

        /** Vetor velocidade (direção de movimentação + velocidade do movimento) da bola. */
        private Vector2D m_vVelocity;

        /** Raio da bola pixels. */
        private int m_iRadius;

        /** Cor da bola. */
        private Color m_oColor;

        /** Indicador a respeito da bola usar a própria gravidade. */
        private boolean m_bOwnGravity;

        /** Vetor de gravidade específico para a bola. */
        private Vector2D m_vOwnGravity;

        /** Indicação de modo de depuração, para desenho do vetor velocidade. */
        private static boolean DEBUG = true;

        /**
         * Fator de ressalto da bola, indicando qual proporção da velocidade a bola deve
         * perder ao se chocar (colidir) com outro objeto no mundo. Valores válidos são
         * no intervalo [0, 1]. O valor 0 indica que a bola simplesmente não quica (isto é,
         * para completamente ao se chocar com algo). O valor 1 indica que a bola quica totalmente
         * (isto é, não perde velocidade alguma ao se chocar).
         */
        private float m_fBounciness;

        /**
         * Construtor padrão. Inicializa a bola com valores predefinidos.
         */
        public Ball() {
            m_iRadius = 25;
            m_fBounciness = 0.8f;
            m_vPosition = new Vector2D(0, 0);
            m_vVelocity = new Vector2D(0, 0);
            m_oColor = Color.red;
            m_bOwnGravity = false;
            m_vOwnGravity = new Vector2D(0, 1);
        }

        public Ball(int iRadius, Color oColor) {
            m_iRadius = iRadius;
            m_fBounciness = 0.8f;
            m_vPosition = new Vector2D(0, 0);
            m_vVelocity = new Vector2D(0, 0);
            m_oColor = oColor;
            m_bOwnGravity = false;
            m_vOwnGravity = new Vector2D(0, 1);
        }

        /**
         * Getter da posição atual da bola.
         * @return Vetor com a posição atual da bola.
         */
        public Vector2D getPosition() {
            return m_vPosition;
        }

        /**
         * Setter da posição atual da bola.
         * @param vPosition Vetor com a nova posição para a bola.
         */
        public void setPosition(Vector2D vPosition) {
            m_vPosition = vPosition;
        }

        /**
         * Getter da velocidade da bola.
         * @return Vetor com a velocidade atual da bola.
         */
        public Vector2D getVelocity() {
            return m_vVelocity;
        }

        /**
         * Setter da velocidade da bola.
         * @param vVelocity Vetor com a nova velocidade da bola.
         */
        public void setVelocity(Vector2D vVelocity) {
            m_vVelocity = vVelocity;
        }

        /**
         * Getter do raio da bola.
         * @return Raio da bola em pixels.
         */
        public int getRadius() {
            return m_iRadius;
        }

        /**
         * Setter do raio da bola.
         * @param iRadius Novo raio da bola, em pixels.
         */
        public void setRadius(int iRadius) {
            m_iRadius = iRadius;
        }

        /**
         * Getter do fator de ressalto da bola.
         * @return Float com o fator de ressalto da bola, no intervalo [0, 1].
         */
        public float getBounciness() {
            return m_fBounciness;
        }

        /**
         * Setter do fator de ressalto da bola.
         * @param fBounciness Float com o fator de ressalto da bola, no intervalo [0, 1].
         * Valores fora do intervalo são ajustados para a extremidade limitante.
         */
        public void setBounciness(float fBounciness) {
            if (fBounciness < 0.0f)
                m_fBounciness = 0.0f;
            else if(fBounciness > 1.0f)
                m_fBounciness = 1.0f;
            else
                m_fBounciness = fBounciness;
        }

        /**
         * Getter da indicação de gravidade específica da bola habilitada.
         * @return Booleano indicando se está ou não habilitada.
         */
        public boolean getOwnGravityEnabled() {
            return m_bOwnGravity;
        }

        /**
         * Setter da indicação de gravidade específica da bola habilitada.
         * @param bEnable Booleano indicando se deve ou não habilitar.
         */
        public void setOwnGravityEnabled(boolean bEnabled) {
            m_bOwnGravity = bEnabled;
        }

        /**
         * Getter da gravidade específica da bola.
         * @return Vetor com a gravidade específica da bola.
         */
        public Vector2D getOwnGravity() {
            return m_vOwnGravity;
        }

        /**
         * Setter da gravidade específica da bola.
         * @param vOwnGravity Vetor com a nova gravidade específica da bola.
         */
        public void setOwnGravity(Vector2D vOwnGravity) {
            m_vOwnGravity = vOwnGravity;
        }

        /**
         * Método de desenho da bola. É chamado pela cena sempre que for necessário
         * repintar a bola.
         * @param g Instância do objeto Graphics para pintura da bola.
         */
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // Simplesmente desenha no Graphics uma bola (mas poderia copiar uma
            // imagem ou um quadro de uma animação).
            Vector2D vTopLeft = new Vector2D(m_vPosition.x - m_iRadius, m_vPosition.y - m_iRadius);
            int iDiameter = 2 * m_iRadius;
            g.setColor(m_oColor);
            g.fillOval((int) vTopLeft.x, (int) vTopLeft.y, iDiameter, iDiameter);

            // Se a depuração está ligada, desenha o vetor velocidade
            if(Ball.DEBUG) {
                g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                Vector2D vVel = m_vVelocity.scalarMult(10); // Escala x10 para facilitar a visualização
                Vector2D vAux = m_vPosition.plus(vVel);
                g.drawLine((int) m_vPosition.x, (int) m_vPosition.y, (int) vAux.x, (int) vAux.y);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Método de atualização do objeto. É chamado a cada quadro do jogo.
         */
        public void update() {
            // Adiciona a gravidade à velocidade da bola
            // Ou seja: Velocidade = Velocidade + Gravidade
            if(!m_bOwnGravity)
                m_vVelocity = m_vVelocity.plus(GameScene.GRAVITY);
            else
                m_vVelocity = m_vVelocity.plus(m_vOwnGravity);

            // Atualiza a posição da bola de acordo com a velocidade (direção e valor)
            m_vPosition = m_vPosition.plus(m_vVelocity);

            // Trata colisões com o mundo e com outras bolas
            handleCollisions();
        }

        /**
         * Método de tratamento das colisões. Simplesmente inverte o vetor nos eixos x e y quando
         * a bola se choca com as bordas do mundo, e calcula o vetor inverso à direção em que as bolas
         * se chocam umas com as outras.
         * OBSERVAÇÃO: É apenas um exemplo BEM SIMPLES, não inclui cálculos da física relativos à quantidade
         * de movimento, coeficientes de restituição, energia elástica, etc.  
         */
        protected void handleCollisions() {
            boolean bCollided = false;

            // Primeiro, trata a colisão com os limites do mundo, simplesmente invertendo
            // a velocidade de acordo com a borda com que a bola colidir.
            Rectangle oBounds = GameScene.BOUNDS;
            if(m_vPosition.x - m_iRadius <= oBounds.x) {
                m_vPosition.x = oBounds.x + m_iRadius;
                m_vVelocity.x *= -1;
                bCollided = true;
            }
            else if(m_vPosition.x + m_iRadius >= oBounds.width) {
                m_vPosition.x = oBounds.width - m_iRadius;
                m_vVelocity.x *= -1;
                bCollided = true;
            }

            if(m_vPosition.y - m_iRadius <= oBounds.y) {
                m_vPosition.y = oBounds.y + m_iRadius;
                m_vVelocity.y *= -1;
                bCollided = true;
            }
            else if(m_vPosition.y + m_iRadius >= oBounds.height) {
                m_vPosition.y = oBounds.height - m_iRadius;
                m_vVelocity.y *= -1;
                bCollided = true;
            }

            // Agora, trata a colisão da bola com as demais bolas
            ArrayList<Ball> lsBalls = GameScene.instance.getBalls();
            for(Ball oOtherBall: lsBalls) {
                if(!oOtherBall.equals(this)) { // Naturalmente, ignora a si próprio

                    // Checar colisão entre círculos é beeeeemmmm fácil!
                    // Duas bolas estão em colisão se a distância entre seus pontos
                    // centrais for menor ou igual do que a soma de seus raios.
                    double dDistance = m_vPosition.distance(oOtherBall.getPosition());
                    if(dDistance <= m_iRadius + oOtherBall.getRadius()) {

                        // Obtém o vetor unitário (normalizado) que aponta para a direção em que a bola colidou com a outra.
                        // Simples aritmética de vetores: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vetor_(matem%C3%A1tica)#Subtra.C3.A7.C3.A3o
                        Vector2D vForceDir = m_vPosition.minus(oOtherBall.getPosition()).unitVector();

                        // Ajusta a posição da bola atual para que ela fique garantidamente "fora"
                        // da outra bola
                        Vector2D vAway = new Vector2D(vForceDir.x, vForceDir.y);
                        vAway.setR(m_iRadius + oOtherBall.getRadius());
                        m_vPosition = oOtherBall.getPosition().plus(vAway);

                        // A "força" com que a bola será ricocheteada é igual à soma das velocidades das duas bolas
                        double dSpeed = m_vVelocity.length() + oOtherBall.getVelocity().length();
                        Vector2D vForce = new Vector2D(vForceDir.x, vForceDir.y);
                        vForce = vForce.scalarMult(dSpeed);

                        // Soma o vetor força com a velocidade da bola
                        m_vVelocity = m_vVelocity.plus(vForce);
                        bCollided = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Aplica o fator de ressalto à bola se ela colidiu com algo
            if(bCollided)
                m_vVelocity = m_vVelocity.scalarMult(m_fBounciness);
        }
    }
```

Essa classe usa e abusa de vetores, e eu honestamente espero que os comentários te ajudem a entender (caso você já não entenda bastante do assunto - caso você entenda, desculpe por eu ser tão didático). Mas o mais importante ai é que você vai notar que ela não herda de nada! O ponto-chave são, novamente, os métodos `update` e `paint`. No método `update`, a velocidade da bola é atualizada com a gravidade e as colisões são verificadas (para diminuir uma pequena parte da velocidade a cada colisão e para alterar a direção da velocidade conforme as colisões). Já no método `paint` a bola é simplesmente desenhada. Fiz um exemplo bem bobo, mas você pode desenhar uma imagem ou mesmo uma animação (desenhando um quadro por vez a cada chamada de `paint`, por exemplo).

A "simulação de física" (se é que ela pode ser assim chamada) é beeeemmmm inocente, mas serve para exemplificar (e pra tornar tudo mais divertido!). O resultado final é uma janela com 5 bolas que se movem e se chocam umas com as outras, algo como ilustra a figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As linhas amarelas são de depuração e indicam os vetores de velocidade. Desligue fazendo `Ball.DEBUG = false;`.

E é isso ai. Boa sorte com o seu jogo. :)

Comment: muito obrigado pessoal, juntei um pouco da resposta de cada um e implementei a thread na mesma classe,criei uma lógica aqui que deu certo, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Bom, você não  "deveria", mas você pode sim fazer uma classe estender de Objeto e utilizá-la numa simulação.

Ex:

```
public class Bola
    extends Thread {

    private float directionX;
    private float posX = 0;
    private boolean should_run;

    Bola(float x, float posX) {
        directionX = x;
        should_run = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (should_run) {
            posX = posX + directionX;
            System.out.println(this + "\tposX:" + posX);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                should_run = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Bola[] bolas =
            { new Bola(1, 0), new Bola(-1, 0) };
        for (Bola bola : bolas) {
            bola.start();
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        bolas[0].should_run = false;
        bolas[1].should_run = false;
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

E por que não deveria?
Imagine que sua simulação tenha um milhão de bolas (partículas). Apesar desse modelo de uma thread por objeto ser convenientemente simples, no final o impacto de ter um milhão de thread *rodando* seria enorme. Seria muito melhor utilizar um Pool de Threads (ou usar algum outro mecanismo mais avançados de paralelização) e implementar cada partícula como uma tarefa (Task).

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer controlar independentemente cada Thread você deve guardar referência para cada objeto criado à partir de sua Runnable e usar os métodos padrão do Ciclo de Vida da Thread para controlá-la. Veja este PDF http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~inf1621/java2.pdf que descreve bem como isso funciona.