# Movimentando círculo na tela com thread e o método paint do jFrame

Tags: java, swing

Estudando o método de desenho do `JFrame` no caso o `paint` e queria fazer um círculo movimentar-se na tela com a utilização de *threads*, porém o círculo não movimenta direito.  Talvez precisaria de um método `movimenta` para definir onde eu quero colocar determinado objeto na tela.

```
public class PackMan extends JFrame implements KeyListener, Runnable{
    JLabel label = null;
    int contador = 0;
    int autura = -1;
    int direita = -2;
    int esquerda = -3;
    int baixo = -4;


    public PackMan(){
        super("PackMan");
        label = new JLabel();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //setLocation(100,100);
        setSize(600, 600);


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        if (g!=null) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillArc(contador, contador, 70, 70, 135, -270);
            g.setPaintMode();

            //repaint();
        }

    }
    public void movimenta(int parametro){

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evento) {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        if(evento.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            repaint();
            movimenta(-1);
            t.start();

        }
        if(evento.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            t.start();
            repaint();
        }
        if(evento.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            t.start();
            repaint();
        }
        if(evento.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            t.start();
            repaint();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PackMan();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {
            while (contador < 600) {
                contador += 1;
                pause();
            }
            contador = 600;
            while (contador > 0) {
                contador -= 1;
                pause();
            }
        }

    }
    public void pause() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

}
```

Comment: obs o metodo movimenta não está incluído no código...

Comment: A sua pergunta ainda não está muito clara. O que quer dizer "não movimenta direito"? Outra coisa, [essa minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4922/73) em outra pergunta similar pode lhe ser útil.

Comment: então Luiz na classe tem um circulo desenhado o que eu queria conseguir fazer seria movimentado para onde eu quiser.

Answer (score 1):

Como eu já havia mencionado no comentário, [essa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4922/73) lhe será bastante útil, principalmente porque lá eu descrevo uma série de necessidades (incluindo principalmente a questão da pintura com *double buffering*).

Para fazer a movimentação que você deseja, a captura de teclas deve alterar a direção da movimentação do personagem. No seu código atual, o seu laço principal do jogo (*game loop*) desconsidera totalmente qualquer código que você possa construir, pois ele continuamente incrementa e depois decrementa a variável `contador`, que você utiliza como posição do seu personagem no momento da pintura.

Uma forma bem simples de solucionar o problema é ter duas variáveis, uma para guardar o valor de X e outra para guardar o valor de Y, e utilizá-las no momento da pintura. Você vai precisar de uma terceira variável para armazenar a direção de movimentação, de forma que dentro do seu laço você deve continuamente incrementar ou decrementar apenas uma das variáveis X e Y *de acordo com essa direção*. Algo como:

```java
while(true) {
    if(direcao == 0) // para cima
        Y = Y - 1
    else if(direcao == 1) // para baixo
        Y = Y + 1
    else if(direcao == 2) // para direita
        X = X + 1
    else if(direcao == 3) // para esquerda
        X = X - 1
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

No caso do PackMan (como você chamou, embora o nome do personagem no jogo original seja PacMan) essa abordagem pode ser suficiente, mas como eu menciono na outra resposta citada há mais detalhes necessários (principalmente porque em geral não se usa threads separadas para diferentes objetos móveis - e eu imagino que eventualmente você irá incluir os fantasmas no jogo, certo?).

Eu alterei o meu código da resposta original pra fazer um exemplo com o seu PackMan. Esse código usa vetores para indicar a movimentação do personagem, e a cena do jogo não usa um JFrame, e sim um JComponent (por causa do *double buffering* já implementado - se você tentar movimentar o personagem forçando chamadas do `repaint` num JFrame verá que a tela não é corretamente pintada). Apesar de usar vetores, a movimentação é bem quadradona (pra cima, pra baixo, esquerda e direita, como no jogo original do PacMan). Mas o uso de vetores permite fazer transições mais suaves no movimento (como no exemplo da bola da resposta original). Se o seu personagem não se mover apenas em cruz, é fácil alterar o código para ao invés de simplesmente trocar a velocidade, adicionar a nova velocidade à velocidade atual para fazer com que ele se mova também em diagonais, por exemplo.

Aqui está o exemplo:

**Classe Game**

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

/**
 * Classe principal, de implementação do jogo.
 * Exemplo para ilustração no SOPT.
 * @author Luiz C. Vieira
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    /** Thread de execução da applet. */
    private Thread m_oMainThread;

    /** Indicador de que o jogo está em execução. */
    private boolean m_bRunning;

    /** Taxa de quadros por segundo (framerate) ideal do jogo. */
    private static float FPS = 1000f / 60f; 

    private boolean m_bUpPressed = false;
    private boolean m_bDownPressed = false;
    private boolean m_bLeftPressed = false;
    private boolean m_bRightPressed = false;

    /**
     * Construtor do jogo.
     */
    public Game() {
        // Define tamanho da janela de jogo
        setSize(800, 600);

        // Adiciona a cena ao jogo
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(GameScene.instance);

        // O jogo não se inicia automaticamente
        m_bRunning = false;

        // Captura do pressionamento e liberação de teclas
        getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "onUpPressed");
        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("onUpPressed", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m_bUpPressed = true;
            }
        });        

        getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), "onUpReleased");
        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("onUpReleased", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m_bUpPressed = false;
            }
        });

        getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "onDownPressed");
        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("onDownPressed", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m_bDownPressed = true;
            }
        });        

        getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "onDownReleased");
        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("onDownReleased", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m_bDownPressed = false;
            }
        });        

        getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "onLeftPressed");
        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("onLeftPressed", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m_bLeftPressed = true;
            }
        });        

        getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "onLeftReleased");
        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("onLeftReleased", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m_bLeftPressed = false;
            }
        });

        getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "onRightPressed");
        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("onRightPressed", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m_bRightPressed = true;
            }
        });        

        getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "onRightReleased");
        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("onRightReleased", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                m_bRightPressed = false;
            }
        });

        // Captura o fechamento da janela para encerrar o jogo
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                stop();
            }
        });        
    }

    /**
     * Método de início do jogo.
     */
    public void start() {
        m_bRunning = true;
        m_oMainThread = new Thread(this);
        m_oMainThread.start();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Método de interrupção do jogo.
     */
    public void stop() {
        m_bRunning = false;
    }

    /**
     * Método getter do atributo de execução do jogo.
     * @return Valor lógico indicando se o jogo está (true) ou não (false) em execução.
     */
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return m_bRunning;
    }

    /**
     * Método de execução da thread da applet do jogo.
     * Basicamente implementa o game loop, atualizando na cena
     * todos os componentes a cada quadro (cada iteração).
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {

        long lPrevious = System.nanoTime() / 1000000;
        long lLag = 0;

        // Gameloop do jogo
        while(m_bRunning) {

            // Contabilização de tempo
            long lCurrent = System.nanoTime() / 1000000;
            long lElapsed = lCurrent - lPrevious;
            lPrevious = lCurrent;
            lLag += lElapsed;

            // Processamento de entrada (teclado, mouse, etc)!
            // Muda a direção da velocidade conforme a tecla pressionada
            Vector2D vVelocity = GameScene.instance.getPackMan().getVelocity();
            if(m_bUpPressed)
                vVelocity = new Vector2D(0, -8);
            else if(m_bDownPressed)
                vVelocity = new Vector2D(0, 8);
            else if(m_bLeftPressed)
                vVelocity = new Vector2D(-8, 0);
            else if(m_bRightPressed)
                vVelocity = new Vector2D(8, 0);
            GameScene.instance.getPackMan().setVelocity(vVelocity);             

            // Atualização do mundo!
            // Faz chamadas de update enquanto o número desejado de quadros
            // por segundo não tiver sido atingido
            while(lLag >= Game.FPS)
            {
                GameScene.instance.update();
                lLag -= Game.FPS;
            }

            // Renderização do jogo!
            GameScene.instance.repaint();
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game oGame = new Game();
        oGame.start();
        while(oGame.isRunning())
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                oGame.stop();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

**Classe GameScene**

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

/**
 * Classe de implementação de cenas de jogo.
 * @author Luiz C. Vieira
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameScene extends JComponent {

    /** Referência estática dos limites do mundo. */
    public static Rectangle BOUNDS = new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600);

    /** Referência ao objeto PackMan. */
    private PackMan m_oPackMan;

    /** Instância singleton da cena. */
    public static GameScene instance = new GameScene();

    /**
     * Construtor protegido.
     */
    protected GameScene() {
        // Cria o personagem do jogo
        m_oPackMan = new PackMan();
    }

    /**
     * Getter do packman.
     * @return Objeto PackMan na cena.
     */
    public PackMan getPackMan() {
        return m_oPackMan;
    }

    /**
     * Método de atualização da cena. É chamado a cada quadro do jogo.
     */
    public void update() {
        // Atualiza todos os objetos em cena
        m_oPackMan.update();
    }

    /**
     * Método de pintura da cena.
     * @param g Intância com o objeto Graphics da applet para pintura. 
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Pinta o fundo da cena (simplesmente todo preto nesse exemplo)
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GameScene.BOUNDS.width, GameScene.BOUNDS.height);

        // Faz a repintura de cada um dos objetos em cena
        m_oPackMan.paint(g);
    }
}
```

**Classe PackMan**

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

/**
 * Classe do PackMan (não seria PacMan? :) ).
 * Ela não implementa thread! Esse controle fica por parte das classes
 * Game e GameScene que executam o método update.
 * @author Luiz C. Vieira
 */
public class PackMan {

    /** Vetor com a posição atual do personagem. */
    private Vector2D m_vPosition;

    /** Vetor velocidade (direção de movimentação + velocidade do movimento) do personagem. */
    private Vector2D m_vVelocity;

    /** Indicação de modo de depuração, para desenho do vetor velocidade. */
    private static boolean DEBUG = true;

    /**
     * Construtor padrão. Inicializa o personagem.
     */
    public PackMan() {
        m_vPosition = new Vector2D(0, 0);
        m_vVelocity = new Vector2D(8, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Getter da posição atual.
     * @return Vetor com a posição atual.
     */
    public Vector2D getPosition() {
        return m_vPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Setter da posição atual.
     * @param vPosition Vetor com a nova posição.
     */
    public void setPosition(Vector2D vPosition) {
        m_vPosition = vPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Getter da velocidade.
     * @return Vetor com a velocidade atual.
     */
    public Vector2D getVelocity() {
        return m_vVelocity;
    }

    /**
     * Setter da velocidade.
     * @param vVelocity Vetor com a nova velocidade.
     */
    public void setVelocity(Vector2D vVelocity) {
        m_vVelocity = vVelocity;
    }

    /**
     * Método de desenho do personagem. É chamado pela cena sempre que for necessário
     * repintar.
     * @param g Instância do objeto Graphics para pintura do personagem.
     */
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // Simplesmente desenha no Graphics o PackMan.

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillArc((int) m_vPosition.x, (int) m_vPosition.y, 70, 70, 135, -270);
        g.setPaintMode();

        // Se a depuração está ligada, desenha o vetor velocidade
        if(PackMan.DEBUG) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            Vector2D vVel = m_vVelocity.scalarMult(10); // Escala x10 para facilitar a visualização
            Vector2D vAux = m_vPosition.plus(vVel);
            g.drawLine((int) m_vPosition.x, (int) m_vPosition.y, (int) vAux.x, (int) vAux.y);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Método de atualização do objeto. É chamado a cada quadro do jogo.
     */
    public void update() {
        // Atualiza a posição de acordo com a velocidade (direção e valor)
        m_vPosition = m_vPosition.plus(m_vVelocity);

        // Trata colisões com o mundo
        handleCollisions();
    }

    /**
     * Método de tratamento das colisões. "Teletransporta" o personagem nos eixos x e y quando
     * ele "some" em um dos cantos da tela.
     */
    protected void handleCollisions() {
        Rectangle oBounds = GameScene.BOUNDS;
        int iWidth = 70; // A mesma largura que você usa no desenho
        int iHeight = 70; // Idem para a altura

        if(m_vPosition.x <= oBounds.x - iWidth)
            m_vPosition.x = oBounds.width + iWidth;
        else if(m_vPosition.x >= oBounds.width + iWidth)
            m_vPosition.x = -iWidth;

        if(m_vPosition.y <= oBounds.y - iHeight)
            m_vPosition.y = oBounds.height + iHeight;
        else if(m_vPosition.y >= oBounds.height + iHeight)
            m_vPosition.y = -iHeight;
   }
}
```

A classe `Vector2D` é a mesma referenciada na minha resposta original. Abaixo uma tela do exemplo em funcionamento (utilize as setas do teclado para alterar a direção de movimento constante):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]