# Thread de um ponto "piscando"

Tags: java, swing, thread

Ola, eu fiz um programa que voce mexe uma bolinha com as setas do teclado so que fica piscando a tela quando mexe. Eu vi outros programas nesse tipo do meu so que nao ficam piscando. Se alguem puder me ajudar...
(o fundo fica normal mas a bolinha enquanto se mexe que pisca)

codigo:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Cobrinha extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private Thread th = new Thread(this);
    private int posEsq = 300;
    private int posTop = 300;
    private int ultTecla = 37;

    public Cobrinha() {
        super("Cobrinha");
        this.setSize(600,600);
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                mover(e.getKeyCode());
            }
        });
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        th.start();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void mover(int tecla) {
        ultTecla = tecla;
    }
    public void run() {
        while (true) { 
            switch (ultTecla) {
                case 38: posTop--; break;
                case 40: posTop++; break;
                case 37: posEsq--; break;
                case 39: posEsq++; break;
            }
            try { th.sleep(6); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            this.repaint(); 
        }
    }        
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.fillOval(posEsq, posTop, 20, 20);
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        new Cobrinha(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Como você pode perceber você recebeu votos para fechar como não clara. A razão certamente é que você não explica corretamente o que é "piscada", não descreve como é a tal "bolinha" e também não oferece uma imagem de exemplo do que acontece. Se for o que eu imagino, essa piscada se chama *flickering* e ocorre porque a repintura total está acontecendo a cada quadro. Herde de `JComponent` ao invés de `JFrame` que deve ajudar por causa do *double buffering*. Dá uma lida nesta minha outra resposta (e na que ela linka) pra entender os detalhes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14283/73

Answer (score 3):

Para utilizar o double buffer no Swing, você pode fazer com que sua classe herde de JPanel, e depois sobrescrever o método paintComponent. Após isso é só inserir sua classe em um JFrame:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Cobrinha extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Thread th = new Thread(this);
    private int posEsq = 300;
    private int posTop = 300;
    private int ultTecla = 37;

    public Cobrinha() {
        setSize(600, 600);
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        th.start();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void mover(int tecla) {
        ultTecla = tecla;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            switch (ultTecla) {
            case 38: posTop--; break;
            case 40: posTop++; break;
            case 37: posEsq--; break;
            case 39: posEsq++; break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(6);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(posEsq, posTop, 20, 20);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cobrinha");
        Cobrinha cobrinha = new Cobrinha();

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                cobrinha.mover(e.getKeyCode());
            }
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(cobrinha);
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```