# Problema com configuração de foco das janelas do Ubuntu ao utilizar Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, thread, jframe

Estava fazendo um programa em que um círculo é desenhado na tela e ele fica andando pela tela, utilizando as classes `JFrame` para criar a janela, uma `thread` para controlar o círculo que eu insiro na tela.

O problema no entanto, está quando eu executo meu programa, pois ao executar no meu Sistema Operacional (Ubuntu 14.04) o círculo parece ficar travando enquanto é redesenhado pela tela, porém ao ficar mexendo com o mouse dentro do programa o círculo é redesenhado perfeitamente. Quando testado em outro SO o programa funcionara perfeitamente.

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma ideia do que eu poderia fazer, seja com relação ao meu SO ou com relação a minha aplicação.

Aqui está os códigos da minha classe círculo que implementa o Runnable:

```
public class Circulo extends JComponent implements Runnable{

private Desenho desenhoCirculo = null;
private int velocidadeCirculo_x;
private int velocidadeCirculo_y;
private Color corCirculo;
private ColisaoCirculo colisao;

public Circulo(Desenho desenhoCirculo, int velocidadeCirculo_x, int velocidadeCirculo_y, Color corCirculo, ColisaoCirculo colisao) {
    this.desenhoCirculo = desenhoCirculo;
    this.velocidadeCirculo_x = velocidadeCirculo_x;
    this.velocidadeCirculo_y = velocidadeCirculo_y;
    this.corCirculo = corCirculo;
    this.colisao = colisao;
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public void mexerCirculo( int x, int y ){
    this.desenhoCirculo.setPos_x( this.desenhoCirculo.getPos_x() + x);
    this.desenhoCirculo.setPos_y( this.desenhoCirculo.getPos_y() + y);
}

public Desenho getDesenhoCirculo() {
    return desenhoCirculo;
}

public void setDesenhoCirculo(Desenho desenhoCirculo) {
    this.desenhoCirculo = desenhoCirculo;
}

public int getVelocidadeCirculo_x() {
    return velocidadeCirculo_x;
}

public void setVelocidadeCirculo_x(int velocidadeCirculo_x) {
    this.velocidadeCirculo_x = velocidadeCirculo_x;
}

public int getVelocidadeCirculo_y() {
    return velocidadeCirculo_y;
}

public void setVelocidadeCirculo_y(int velocidadeCirculo_y) {
    this.velocidadeCirculo_y = velocidadeCirculo_y;
}

public Color getCorCirculo() {
    return corCirculo;
}

public void setCorCirculo(Color corCirculo) {
    this.corCirculo = corCirculo;
}

public ColisaoCirculo getColisao() {
    return colisao;
}

public void setColisao(ColisaoCirculo colisao) {
    this.colisao = colisao;
}



@Override
public void paint( Graphics g ){
    g.setColor(corCirculo);
    g.fillOval(desenhoCirculo.getPos_x(), desenhoCirculo.getPos_y(), desenhoCirculo.getLargura(), desenhoCirculo.getAltura());
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while( true ){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
            this.mexerCirculo( this.velocidadeCirculo_x, this.velocidadeCirculo_y );
            this.colisao.checarColisaoComLimitesTela( this );
            repaint();

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Circulo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: O conteúdo a sua thread é muito grande? Talvez devesse postá-lo aqui.

Comment: O seu problema parece ser realmente o tempo gasto para a pintura. Tente fazer a pintura no método `paintComponent` ao invés de fazer no método `paint` (já que você herda de `JComponent`) - e não esqueça de invocar o método original da classe pai antes de pintar o seu círculo! Essa outra resposta pode ajudar com algumas explicações adicionais (principalmente sobre o tal de *double buffering*): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4703/como-usar-uma-thread-espec%C3%ADfica-de-uma-classe-com-m%C3%BAltiplas-threads/4922#4922

Comment: O Ubuntu, como a maioria das distribuição Linux, apresentam problemas com os drivers de placa de vídeo. E acaba acontecendo erros como esse. Você pode olhar se existe o driver oficial da sua placa de vídeo para essa versão do Ubuntu.