# Criar algoritmo para simulação de fluido?

Tags: algoritmo, jogos

Eu quero criar um game de simulação com o unity e preciso simular o movimento de fluidos 2D, não consigo pensar numa forma de criar um algoritmo com performance o bastante para simular mil partículas e ainda sobrar poder de processamento Pra outras tarefas que exigem a informação sobre a velocidade do fluido.
 Praticamente todo o jogo vai ser baseado em milhares de partículas sofrendo e aplicando forças dentro de um meio liquido invisivel em tempo real.
Existe uma tática de cálculo de força que não exija percorrer todas as partículas a procura das mais próximas?.

Answer (score 10):

Sim, existem algumas estratégias. Pra começar você não simula o "oceano" todo. Você simula apenas a área ou região do fluído que terá algum contato com o avatar do jogador (ou de um NPC). Por exemplo, suponha que o jogador pule numa piscina. Você vai simular o fluído apenas na superfície da piscina. O restante, abaixo, é uma região azul simplesmente.

Outra estratégia comum é você simular fluído apenas na região visível ao jogador (o que depende de posicionamento de câmera). No caso da Unity, uma solução pode ser você construir uma pequena caixa com o emissor de partículas da simulação do fluído e colocá-la imediatamente embaixo do avatar. Deslocando essa área juntamente com o avatar, ele pode ter a percepção de estar interagindo com uma superfície líquida maior. Talvez vc precise controlar a interação da física de elementos externos (caso contrário, ao "mover" a pequena piscina juntamente com o avatar a inércia vai mover o líquido de forma inesperada).

Se por acaso a visão do jogador inclui muito da superfície do líquido (ele está correndo sobre as ondas na praia, por exemplo), você pode ter construído a animação da superfície do líquido fora do jogo, assim ela não requer tanto processamento. De todas as formas, o esquema de malha de superfície que a Unity usa é bem bacana (e usa bastante o a GPU), de forma que dificilmente se precisa disso a não ser que a plataforma seja bastante limitada (dispositivos móveis, por exemplo).

Por fim, se você desejar controlar totalmente o desempenho (e sabendo que se trata de um jogo 2D), talvez seja mais fácil você mesmo implementar alguma coisa simples. Não use a física da Unity e calcule as colisões você mesmo usando partículas circulares grandes. A vantagem de fazer assim ao invés de ter um zilhão de partículas pequenas é que:

1. O teste de colisão fica bem simples, pois basta verificar os raios dos círculos (qualquer dúvida sobre colisão de círculos, abra outra pergunta - de todas as formas, [essa minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4922/73) aqui tem um exemplo bem simples).
2. Aplicando um filtro sobre a imagem renderizada, você transforma facilmente um pequeno número de círculos em um "blob" que parece o líquido.

Esse processo funciona da seguinte forma: as bolinhas são controladas pela física; a cada quadro, antes de apresentar (de renderizar), primeiro se aplica um [filtro Gaussiano](http://www2.ic.uff.br/~aconci/G-LoG.PDF) ou de média para "borrar" a imagem (fácil de implementar se não tiver pronto já - também cabe outra pergunta) e depois se faz uma [limiarização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)) pra "juntar" tudo e fazer parecer líquido. Exemplo do processo sendo executado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa imagem é de [um ótimo tutorial](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2012/02/03/) que inclui [código pronto em Java](https://github.com/skeeto/fun-liquid) (fácil de portar para C#).

> P.S.: Ainda assim, note que você não deve fazer essa simulação para
>   todo o "oceano". Apenas para a superfície. [Aqui tem um exemplo em
>   Flash](http://www.patrickmatte.com/stuff/physicsLiquid/) onde se pode ver como essa "mágica" não afeta a percepção no
>   resultado final. E [aqui tem um exemplo em WebGL](http://nullprogram.com/fun-liquid/webgl/) onde dá pra "desligar" esses passos e ver como eles 
>   afetam o resultado final.
>
> P.S.2.: O link no filtro Gaussiano acima pode parecer amedrontador
>   pela equação, mas é só questão de fazer o cálculo. A aplicação dele é
>   a mesma descrita na aplicação do filtro Sobel [nesta minha outra
>   resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/125339/73). A limiarização também é bem simples. [Esta minha outra
>   resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105794/73) pode ser de alguma ajuda (esta, com código em C# mesmo).

Sobre o teste de colisão entre as partículas, uma estratégia de melhoria de desempenho é usar alguma estrutura de dados para manter informação a respeito da posição espacial de cada partícula - digo, além da mera coordenada x, y. Assim, você pode limitar os testes de colisão apenas às partículas que *sabidamente* se encontram mais próximas.

Uma forma simples e direta é simplesmente dividir "a tela" em 4 quadrantes. Conforme as partículas se movem, você atualiza o posicionamento delas fazendo-as entrar/sair de um quadrante. Dessa forma, no cálculo da colisão você apenas testa com as partículas que estiverem no mesmo quadrante. Esse processo pode ser melhorado com uma estrutura de dados mais apropriada. Por exemplo, se você manter uma [QuadTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (no caso de jogos 2D; no caso de 3D seria uma Octree) com as partículas, pode rapidamente decidir as melhores regiões para o teste. Um texto sobre detecção de colisão com QuadTree você encontra [neste documento](http://docslide.com.br/documents/algoritmos-para-deteccao-de-colisoes-em-ambientes-graficos-bidimensionais.html).

Há outras técnicas (leia sobre os tópicos nos slides sobre "Subdivisão de Espaço" [nesta apresentação](http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/EspJogos/AulaColisao/Colisao.pptx.pdf)), mas aí o assunto se estende um bocado. Procure por "colisão" + "jogos" aqui mesmo que há outras perguntas, aliás.

Comment: Obrigado, vou ver os links, na verdade o jogo não terá npcs, ele será totalmente baseado em partículas com carga e sem carga em um meio líquido de interação global não visível, então eu preciso simular todas as partículas simultaneamente. Sem que aja perda de performance. Parece interessante usar esse quadtree.

Comment: Ah, bom. Nesse caso quase tudo o que eu mencionei não serve pra vc. Desculpa pelo puxão de orelha... mas poxa, você podia ter dado mais detalhes na pergunta e facilitado a minha (e a sua) vida né? É, nesse caso o que te resta mesmo é usar uma QuadTree e separar as partículas em regiões de comparação. Boa sorte! :)