# Detectar colisão entre cantos dos objetos

Tags: java, swing, detecção-de-colisão

Estou escrevendo um jogo baseado no [breakout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_(video_game)), mas não estou conseguindo pensar numa forma de detectar a colisão entre o canto da área da bolinha e o paddle, para poder inverter a direção horizontal da bolinha.

Na minha classe `Ball`, tenho um método que cuida do movimento da bolinha, e quando detecta colisão, apenas inverte a direção vertical(eixo y).

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Ball {

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 15;
    private final int DIAMETER = 30;
    private int xSpeed = 1;
    private int ySpeed = 1;

    private Board board;

    public Ball(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
        y = board.paddle.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
        x = board.getPreferredSize().width / 2 - DIAMETER / 2;
    }

    public void move() {

        if (x > board.getWidth() - DIAMETER || x < 0) {
            xSpeed = -xSpeed;
        }

        if (y < 15) {
            ySpeed = -ySpeed;
        }

        if (y > board.getHeight() - DIAMETER) {
            board.gameOver();
        }

        //entre nesta if quando uma colisão é detectada
        if (collision()) {
            y = board.paddle.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
        }

        x += xSpeed;
        y += ySpeed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.xSpeed = speed;
        this.ySpeed = speed;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.fillOval(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
    }

    public boolean collision() {
        //detecta colisão entre a area da bola e o paddle
        return board.paddle.getBounds().intersects(this.getBounds());
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
    }
}
```

O resultado até agora:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que quando a área da bolinha colide com a quina do paddle, ela continua a trajetoria do eixo x, e para simular uma física mais real, gostaria de poder detectar quando a colisão ocorrer nas extremidades dos objetos e inverter a trajetória do eixo X da bolinha. Como detecto isso?

Como são 4 classes grandes diferentes, pra não bagunçar a pergunta, coloquei um exemplo totalmente executável e completo do código no [gist](https://gist.github.com/diegofelipem/5fecda3d81d26a4c9db5af0eff9168d9).

Comment: Paddle é a área que a bolinha anda?

Comment: @jbueno Paddle é a "barra horizontal" que o jogador controla pros lados para rebater a bola.

Comment: `(x, y)` seria o ponto superior esquerdo do quadrado circunscrito ao círculo?

Comment: @jbueno x e y na classe ball seria isso: http://i.imgur.com/OxOBAlm.jpg

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No caso desse jogo, o que vc quer fazer é bem simples.

Quando a sua colisão acontece, a bolinha está *necessariamente* tocando a parte superior do bastão (*paddle*). Sendo assim, o valor do eixo `y` não importa. Você precisa comparar o valor do eixo `x` *de forma relativa*.

Por relativa eu quero dizer que você precisa verificar o quanto o valor em `x` da bolinha está deslocado do valor em `x` central do bastão. Faça assim (pseudo-código):

```
centro_bastao = bastao.x + (bastao.width / 2);
posRelativa = Math.abs(bola.x - centro_bastao) / (bastao.width / 2);
```

O valor de `posRelativa` será entre `0` e `1` de forma que `0` significa que a bolinha está exatamente no centro e `1` a bolinha está exatamente numa das pontas. Se quiser saber qual a ponta (isto é, o lado), tire o `abs` do código acima e verifique o sinal (negativo será na esquerda e positivo na direita). Aí tome a decisão conforme o valor dessa variável.

> P.S.: Idealmente você deveria mover a bola usando um [vetor
>   velocidade](http://www.sofisica.com.br/conteudos/Mecanica/Cinematica/vetores2.php) (isto é, um vetor com a direção e a magnitude da
>   velocidade de movimento). Assim, seria mais fácil "refletir" o vetor
>   simplesmente rotacionando-o conforme o valor de `posRelativa` e depois
>   invertendo-o (0 não rotaciona, e a inversa é exatamente a força a ser
>   aplicada de volta pra cima). Foge do escopo desse site dar uma aula
>   disso, mas sugiro ler na Internet a respeito. É algo importante de se
>   conhecer para desenvolver jogos. [Esta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4922/73) tem
>   algo nesse sentido e pode ser útil também.

Comment: Uma discussão que estávamos tendo no chat é que, ao considerar os limites do círculo como sendo um retângulo, vide método `getBounds`, esta colisão será detectada não quando o círculo em si tocar o bastão, mas quando o retângulo que define seu limite toca. Isso geraria um aspecto visual inesperado, se estou certo.

Comment: De fato, sim, mas não entra no escopo do problema, como comentado pelo Diego.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Está totalmente certo. Mas não tem *almoço grátis*: precisão é custosa. Esse problema que você aponta pode ser resolvido de várias formas. [Pixel perfeito](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tohIDYPWmLY) (checar pixel a pixel) é o mais preciso, mas o mais custoso. O AP poderia continuar usando os bounding boxes retangulares para a primeira detecção e, no caso afirmativo, validar com um pixel perfeito. Ou usar um colisor circular. Há muito material na Internet a respeito.

Comment: Estou lendo os links da resposta. É bem mais complexo que imaginei, vou ter que dar uma estudada, esse conceito de vetor pra velocidade é novo pra mim xD

Comment: Acredite, vai ser um bom estudo pra sua carreira em gamedev. :) Mas vc não precisa necessariamente usar vetores nessa sua primeira versão. Boa sorte!

Comment: Fica aqui mais uma dica: o livro "Programming Game AI by Example" tem um capítulo inicial de matemática que é bem útil. Nele tem uma seção só sobre vetores. Eu sugiro que vc compre o livro (vai ser muito útil pra vc por muito tempo!), mas se vc procurar vc deve achar o PDF (ilegal!) por aí. https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Example-Wordware-Developers-Library/dp/1556220782

Comment: Luiz, sua fórmula funcionou! eu só time que fazer uma modificação por causa do fato de usar retangulo na colisão, ai o que o programa considera como posição x é a ponta(invisivel) do retangulo, e não a área de contato da esfera.[+]

Comment: [+], daí, modifiquei a formula para o seguinte: `posRelativa = ((bola.x + bola.diametro/2) - centro_bastao) / (bastao.width / 2);` e consegui deixar a inversão mais realista :D

Comment: @LuizVieira Não querendo abusar da sua boa vontade, mas faz ideia de como seria possível simular um vetor velocidade neste caso?

Comment: @jbueno Sim, é possível. Ao invés de manipular direta e individualmente `x` e `y`, use um vetor para descrever o movimento da bolinha. O código da minha outra resposta que eu referencio tem exatamente esse exemplo. Dá uma olhada na detecção de colisões, principalmente quando uma bola se choca com a outra. O código detecta isso, e aplica uma "força" (soma um vetor força no vetor velocidade atual da bola) que a impulsiona na direção contrária. A própria gravidade, nesse mesmo exemplo, também é uma força que continuamente atua no vetor velocidade (é simplesmente somada a cada quadro).